# Why do politicians all say "and" when they state a year number

Tags: grammatical-number

"In two thousand AND eight blah blah blah until two thousand AND thirteen blah blah blah"  Is there some grammar rule that if you're stating a year you should say "and" within a number or is there a rule that in politics you should say "and" within a number?

Comment: Which politicians?

Comment: There are some American grammar school teachers who teach that you should never say "and" within a number. I believe that the more colloquial way to do it is to use "and". Politicians like to sound colloquial.

Comment: Peter, it is also the way to do it in the UK. Not including the word *and* seems to be an American thing in particular.

Comment: Leaving out ‘and’, while perfectly common in many dialects (and idiolects), just sounds plain wrong to me. It grates, even though I know there's nothing universally wrong with it. I'm sure there are many who feel the same about leaving the ‘and’ in.

Comment: There has been much written about this already. Long story short: for roughly 1000 years, it was convenient to split up the year by century and year; e.g., 1673 was "sixteen seventy-three". But when the year 2000 came along, that didn't seem to work so good any more. Throw in the by-the-decades old debate about how to pronounce _2001: A Space Odyssey_, and things got even murkier the following year. Anyhow, one can read more [here](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/hendrikhertzberg/2013/01/twenty-something.html) or [here](http://www.youhaventlived.com/qblog/2005/QBlog020105A.html).

Comment: @Tristan - for what it's worth, [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/it-two-thousand-and-ten-or-two-thousand-ten) agrees with your assertion.

Comment: "And" in the middle of a number actually means it's a decimal point.  "Two thousand and thirteen" actually means 2000.13.  This is not a matter of preference or taste.  It is a rule.

Comment: Joe C, that is not the case in the UK. This is a US/UK difference.

Comment: @JoeC: No, that is not a rule. ‘And’ does not mean decimal point anywhere near as often as it is simply a part of a number exceeding 100 (or, if you count the archaic, ‘German’ way of putting the tens last, exceeding 20). If you want to denote decimal points, use ‘point’ for clarity; otherwise, you’re bound to be misunderstood. In fact, if you use ‘and’ like that without specifying what unit follows, I’d say you’re absolutely _certain_ to be misunderstood. “Two thousand and thirteen” can just as well be thirteen millionths as hundredths.

Comment: @JoeC, I was taught that rule too. But that doesn't mean it's a rule that will actually help to understand how most people actually speak.

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/how-to-write-numbers-in-words

Comment: It's 'a rule' to drive on the left hand side of the road. But it's not a rule I'd demand that everyone should stick to in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it's a rule of grammar, but the word "and" can resolve ambiguity in expressing decimal numbers:

```
200.014 = two hundred and fourteen thousandths
0.214 = two hundred fourteen thousandths
```

Let this direct your habits as you see fit.

Comment: That doesn’t really resolve any ambiguity—many people would understand both those to mean _0.214_. If you want to be unambiguous, say “two hundred point zero one four” and “(zero) point two one four”, respectively.

Comment: Interesting that a reply to a purely American question (it would be really odd to leave out the _and_ in a year in British English) brings in another purely American usage: I don't believe I have **ever** heard somebody in England refer to a decimal as so many hundredths or thousandths: those numbers would always be _two hundred  point oh one four_ (or _zero one four_). I've only ever encountered the usage in American novels. (There is the obsolescent unit _thou_, which means "thousandth of an inch", but that is different).

Comment: Putting the 'and' in can also have advantages in spoken English at least: two hundred and three foot-high bushes // two hundred three foot high bushes (I've omitted the required hyphen/s from the written form, as the spoken version would not indicate the different senses without unusual prosody). Let this direct your habits as you see fit.