# spelling numbers

Tags: numbers, letter-writing

How can I spell the number 125.000?

Should I say one hundred twenty five thousand or one hundred and twenty five thousand?

Which is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you correctly say large numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37958/how-do-you-correctly-say-large-numbers) and [Rule for adding and or hyphens between numbers that are spelled out fully ...](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10687/rule-for-adding-and-or-hyphens-between-numbers-that-are-spelled-out-fully-in-t?rq=1).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a difference between US and British English.

Americans say "One hundred twenty five thousand."

British say "One hundred and twenty five thousand".

Canadians side with the Americans. Other than that I don't know which other countries say which.

Comment: The downvote is for not checking for the to-be-expected duplicates (the top candidate in the 'Related' column is one).