# A thousand / one hundred AND one?

Tags: writing-style, numbers

Are the numbers in the title written correctly? I always thought it was one thousand and not a thousand or one hundred one instead of one hundred and one. So which is correct?

- One thousand **or** A thousand
- One hundred one **or** One hundred and one

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Restrict the post to one point -- "a thousand vs. one thousand" or "thousand one vs. thousand and one."

Comment: The question is unclear at the moment. Try putting the alternatives on separate lines: leave a blank line, then start the next line with a dash ("-"), followed by "a thousand and one" or whatever, then write the alternative on the next line, starting again with a dash.

Comment: How you write numbers out depends greatly on context. Are you doing math problems, writing checks, writing business letters, or texting a friend?

Comment: For the "and" question, see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373504/which-came-first-when-saying-numbers-one-hundred-and-one-or-one-hundred-one and https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/american-vs-british-english-meaning-of-one-hundred-and-fifty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brits tend to use "a thousand" and "hundred and one" (and "a half").
Americans tend to use "one thousand" and "hundred one" (and "one half").
So depends on your culture.

Comment: This would be better with some kind of citations or evidence to support your point.

Comment: In fact, the Google Ngram Viewer suggests that Americans, like British speakers, actually tend to use "hundred and one" (the less common "hundred one" is not as uncommon in the US as it is in the UK, but in neither country is it more common than "hundred and one").

Answer (score 0):

Both "a thousand" and "one thousand" are correct and very rarely, either one of them apply to a situation and the other might sound just a little odd. 
"One hundred and one" is the correct one but I guess "one hundred one" might also do.

Comment: Please cite your sources.